# java Passing variables from one class to another

Tags: java, class

I have an error for the code below. Sorry if this is too basic as I am new to java.
Basically, I cannot retrieve the String "44418" from the class `CityChange`.
I know the reason is because I created a new instance `cc` in the class `MainPanel`.
However I do not know any other way of doing it.

```
public class CityChange extends JPanel {
  public CityChange() {
    JButton btn1 = new JButton("London")
    this.add(btn1);
    btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //London Yahoo Weather Code 44418 
        setCitySelected("44418");
      }
    });
  }
  public void setCitySelected(String citySelected) {
    this.citySelected = citySelected;
  }
  public String getCitySelected() {
    return citySelected;
  }
  private String citySelected;
}

public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
  public MainPanel() {
    CityChange cc = new CityChange();
    System.out.println(cc.getCitySelected()); //returns null instead of 44418
  }
}
```

Please give some advice. Thank you.

Comment: can you give the code for `setCitySelected()` and `getCitySelected()`

Comment: It will return the expected value after you will click on your button. Is not it doing it? Only the button click listener setting the expected value.

Comment: Have you clicked the button to provoke the actionPerformed action? How do you know it returns null since you are not printing or affection the returned value? Something's missing here.

Comment: @sircapsalot `public void setCitySelected(String citySelected) {this.citySelected = citySelected}` and `public String getCitySelected { return citySelected }` in class `CityChange`.

Comment: You did not fire any event before calling getCitySelected() in the MainPanel constructor, right? So why should there be any selected city?

Comment: @vojta any suggestion of how to do it?

Comment: @user2875021 Add a JLabel to your CityChange panel. Then add your CityChange panel into your MainPanel in the constructor of MainPanel. In the action listener of "London" button set the "44418" string into the text of the JLabel. Start the application. Click on "London" button. "44418" will appear in the JLabel.

(I have no idea what your code should do, so I just want to show you some "working" idea)

Comment: @vojta I understand that part. It is easy to make it in one class. However, what I am trying to solve is to get the `String citySelected` in another class. If i am creating a new instance, the value will becomes `null`. and that is what I am avoiding.

Comment: @user2875021 Again, it is not an issue of different classes, but an issue of timing.

Comment: @user2875021 The variable belongs to instance of your CityChange panel. If you want to share it among all instances of CityChange panel, mark the variable "static".

Answer (score 0):

For timing reasons, the value has no choice but to be `null`.

What happens here "immediately" (at init time) is that a new `CityChange` object is created and its `citySelected` is gotten and printed. As nobody set it otherwise, it is `null`.

Only after firing the event (clicking the button), it gets a value, and if you print the value then, you'll see the new value.

Comment: I am trying to `setCitySelected("44418")` when the button is clicked. Then passing and getting this `String` or method `getCitySelected()` from `MainPanel` class and that is the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

The code `setCitySelected("44418");` is only executed when you call the method `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)` which is not happening at the moment. This Method is only called via a Button in a GUI so you first need at least a simple Window with a Button. Here is a good example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Comment: I am trying to `setCitySelected("44418")` once the button is clicked. Then goes to another frame with all the details of the city weather. So this means I have to pass the `String` to another class. But then if I am creating a new instance in `MainPanel` class, the String value will becomes null.